# Flash builder 4.5.1 no output on device emulator

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I installed the new version of FB 4.5.1 on a Win 7 x64 machine and tried the [HelloWorld application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/hello-world.html), but I can't see any output on the Google Droid Pro emulator. How can I fix this?

Comment: Example works fine for me, can you post your code here or to pastbin to see if something was fat-fingered? :)

Comment: I exported the files here : http://bit.ly/rfpTZb . Also, the code here (http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/flex/employee-directory-android-flex/flex-mobile-workshop.zip) has no output in the device emulator..its blank when I run it

Answer (score 0):

Got the error finally while debugging. It said :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.at ominds::Firebug$/connect()

Just removed this from mm.cfg PreloadSWF=C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles******\extensions\flashfirebug@o-minds.com\chrome\content\flashfirebug\flashfirebug.swf

weird error!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google Droid Pro emulator use the same PreloadSWF option as FlashFirebug extension, 
first be sure that you update flashfirebug to version 3, then goto flash tab in firebug and from this tab menu select settings then change the mm.cfg settings from default to custom profile then save and everything should work fine